AWS Cloudwatch Agent - How to assign dimensions based on ec2 tags
For each spun up instance I am assigning specific tags which I would like to be included as a dimension for each metric pushed. I don't seem to be able to get it as it does not replace it with value and it seems to be misterious how to achieve it as there are no documentation only bits and pieces of information.
"agent": {
"metrics_collection_interval": 60,
"logfile": "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log"
},
"metrics": {
"namespace": "CustomEC2",
"metrics_collected": {
  "mem": {
    "measurement": [
      "mem_used_percent"
    ],
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60
  },
  "disk": {
    "measurement": [
      "used_percent"
    ],
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
    "resources": [
      "/tmp"
    ],
    "append_dimensions": {
      "taskType": "${aws:ec2:tag:task_type}"
    }
}

I don't see any errors in the logs. How can I achieve such behaviour?
